# How to return TRecord from service Implementation?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-7.0

I work on blazor web application with .Net core 7. i face issue I can't return TRecord from service .

so on service my issue is can't return `TRecord` when apply pagination for get all items .

my issue exactly on the following line of code on service

```
IQueryable<TRecord> query = _context.ServerNames;
```

details of implementation service as below :

```
public interface IserverNamesService : IRepository<ServerNames>
        {

            ListQueryResult<ServerNames> GetItems(ListQueryRequest request);
        }
 

        public ListQueryResult<ServerNames> GetItems(ListQueryRequest request)
        {
        // here i face issue implementing  service
            IQueryable<TRecord> query = _context.ServerNames;
            query = query
                .Skip(request.StartIndex)
                .Take(request.PageSize);

            query = query
                   .Join(_context.ServerTypes,
                   sn => sn.ServerTypeId,
                   st => st.ServerTypeId,
                   (sn, st) => new ServerNames
                   {
                       ServerID = sn.ServerID,
                       server_Name = sn.server_Name,
                       ServerType = st.ServerType
                   });

        
            var list = query.ToList();
            return list;
           
        }
```

pagination modules

```
 public  record ListQueryRequest
    {
        public int StartIndex { get; init; } = 0;
        public int PageSize { get; init; } = 1000;  //set at some maximum epected count for no paging
        public CancellationToken Cancellation { get; set; } = new();
    }
  public  record ListQueryResult<TRecord>
    {
        public IEnumerable<TRecord> Items { get; init; } = Enumerable.Empty<TRecord>();
        public bool Successful { get; init; }
        public string Message { get; init; } = string.Empty;
        public int TotalCount { get; init; }

        private ListQueryResult() { }

        public static ListQueryResult<TRecord> Success(IEnumerable<TRecord> Items, int totalCount, string? message = null)
            => new ListQueryResult<TRecord> { Successful = true, Items = Items, TotalCount = totalCount, Message = message ?? string.Empty };

        public static ListQueryResult<TRecord> Failure(string message)
            => new ListQueryResult<TRecord> { Message = message };
    }
```

my issue image as below :
[image: issue return list]

**Updated answer :**

I face issue on returned function
as image above

**Updated post :**

when try to call service inside controller server names
I get error as below :

i try :

```
[Route("/api/[controller]/listquery")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ListQueryResult<ServerNames> ListQuery([FromBody] ListQueryRequest query)
        { 
      return Ok( _IserverNamesService.GetItems(query));
        }
```

but I get error as below :

[image: CALL CONTROLLER ACTION ISSUE]
so how to solve issue above

Comment: Replace TRecord with ServetNames.

Comment: i make it but issue still exist when return var list = query.ToList();
            return list;

Comment: can you check last updated post

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to define the concrete type in `IQueryable<ServerNames>`.
2. The return type is `ListQueryResult<ServerNames>` not a list.  You need to construct the return object.

```cs
public ListQueryResult<ServerNames> GetItems(ListQueryRequest request)
{
    // You will get concurrency problems here as your application gets more complex
    // If you don't switch to a DbConbtextFactory
    IQueryable<ServerNames> query = _context.ServerNames;

    // Materialize the query to get the total records
    // We need to get this for the pager control
    var recordCount = query.Count();

    // define the page we want in the query
    query = query
        .Skip(request.StartIndex)
        .Take(request.PageSize);

    // Define the join
    query = query
            .Join(_context.ServerTypes,
            sn => sn.ServerTypeId,
            st => st.ServerTypeId,
            (sn, st) => new ServerNames
            {
                ServerID = sn.ServerID,
                server_Name = sn.server_Name,
                ServerType = st.ServerType
            });


    // Materialize the list
    var list = query.ToList();

    // Construct a resturn result object
    return ListQueryResult<ServerNames>.Success(list, count);
}
```

Note two issues that you will occur as your application gets more complex.

DB access is normally an asynchronous activity:

1. You should move over to Async calls into your data pipeline.
2. You should use a DBContext Factory, not a single DbContext.

### Controller

The `HttpResponseMessage` will be constructed for you: just pass back the object you want to send.

```cs
[Route("/api/[controller]/listquery")]
[HttpPost]
public ListQueryResult<ServerNames> ListQuery([FromBody] ListQueryRequest query)
{ 
    return _IserverNamesService.GetItems(query);
}
```

And client side, check the `HttpResponseMessage` status and if it's good deserialize the returned object.

```cs
       ListQueryResult<ServerNames>? result = null;

         var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<ListQueryRequest>($"/api/servernames/listquery", request, request.Cancellation);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ListQueryResult<ServerNames>>();

        return result ?? ListQueryResult<ServerNames>.Failure($"{response.StatusCode} = {response.ReasonPhrase}"); ;
```

Comment: can you see updated answer

Comment: i get error when call service inside controller so how to solve it please